# How to do Domain site name translation (DA module)

Tags: i18n-l10n, domain-access

I just want to translate site name to different language - so when users browse a domain in english they see **English site name**, and when they browse in polish for example, they see **Polska nazwa strony**.

I got all modules ([Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain), [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n), [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable)) and I had enabled two languages, checked variable (site name) in admin/config/regional/i18n/variable - but I can't translate the site name.

I try to translate it on admin/config/system/site-information page - different name for en patch and different for pl - no results, and on admin/structure/domain/view/X/config - also without any results.

Any idea how to menage to translate site name? Am I doing something wrong?

I have tried the [Domain Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_variable) module also already (as suggested in one of the answers), with no avail. I have read [this nice article by Jose](http://reyero.net/drupal/internationalization_domain_access_multilingual_variables_for_each_domain), but it just doesn't work on my site (Drupal 7.38, Domain Access 3.11 and latest version of the [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) module). I did set everything step by step, but I can't figure out what is going on and why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The project page of the "[Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain)" module says:

> If you use the contributed [i18n module suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n), you should use the [Domain Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_variable) module instead of the provided Domain Configuration and Domain Settings modules.

Therefore, I think you should try the [Domain Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_variable) module, to check if it fixes you issue.